# Effect on Alertness of Nutrients

Tags: nutrition, micronutrients

My question in its simplest sense is: would a person avoiding complex carbohydrates, but having adequate essential nutrients, be more likely to lack alertness during the day? Are carbohydrates essential to alertness?

Perhaps I should ask as well: in terms of immediate energy, is a complex carbohydrate snack (e.g. a fruit) more efficient / only efficient to boost alertness compared to other nutrients?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE. Please take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help docs](https://health.stackexchange.com/help). Please edit and clarify your question. Currently it is a bit unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I have attempted to clarify it, I have edited the question.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. If you have researched this question before please include a bit from that as well.